# Tooltips over datepicker calendar

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-tooltip

I want to show tooltips when mouse is over a date in a jquery ui datepicker calendar. This is my code for creating the calendar and for adding the tooltip. Everything works except tooltips.

```
function check_in_out_enable2(in_date, out_date) {
"use strict";
var today, prev_date;
today = new Date();
jQuery("#" + in_date).datepicker({
    dateFormat : "yy-mm-dd",
    minDate: today,
    beforeShowDay: enableAllTheseDays

}, jQuery.datepicker.regional[control_vars.datepick_lang]).datepicker('widget').wrap('<div class="ll-skin-melon"/>');

jQuery("#" + in_date).change(function () {
    prev_date = new Date(jQuery('#' + in_date).val());

    jQuery("#" + out_date).datepicker("destroy");
    jQuery("#" + out_date).datepicker({
        dateFormat : "yy-mm-dd",
        minDate: prev_date,
        beforeShowDay: enableAllTheseDays
    }, jQuery.datepicker.regional[control_vars.datepick_lang]);
});


jQuery("#" + out_date).datepicker({
    dateFormat : "yy-mm-dd",
    minDate: today,
    beforeShowDay: enableAllTheseDays
}, jQuery.datepicker.regional[control_vars.datepick_lang]);

jQuery("#" + in_date + ",#" + out_date).change(function (event) {
    jQuery(this).parent().removeClass('calendar_icon');
});

jQuery("#" + in_date+ " .highlight a").tooltip();
jQuery("#" + out_date+ " .highlight a").tooltip();

}
check_in_out_enable2('start_date', 'end_date');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution.
Instead of

```
jQuery("#" + in_date+ " .highlight a").tooltip();
jQuery("#" + out_date+ " .highlight a").tooltip();
```

i used a custom tooltip

```
jQuery("html").on("mouseenter",".freetobook .ui-state-default", function() {
    var price;
    price = jQuery(this).parent().attr('title');
    jQuery(this).append('<span class="hover_price">'+price+'</span>');
});

jQuery("html").on("mouseleave",".freetobook", function() {
    //jQuery(this).find('.hover_price').remove();
});
```